# Wiki da comunidade

Tags: debate, wiki-comunitário

Desculpem a ignorância, mas recebi a pouco o privilégio `Editar Wiki Da Comunidade`, e procurei e não achei a wiki. o que seria essa wiki da comunidade?

Comment: Tecnicamente, não é duplicata porque a outra lá não tem resposta. Mas acho que se alguém for responder é melhor fazer lá e marcamos esta como dup. >>>>> [Como funciona a marcação de “Wiki da Comunidade”](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/762/201)

Comment: Mesclada a pergunta com a que o brasofilo indicou, que já está no formato FAQ. A resposta migrou pra lá.